# MS Office SaveAs type FileDialog with a filter in vb

Tags: vba, ms-office, filedialog

I want to create a 'save as' file dialog with a filter, but this doesn't seem possible using the FileDialog class (Microsoft Office 12.0 Object Library). The documentation actually mentions this [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa190813%28v=office.10%29.aspx), see last paragraph, but gives no reason as to why? Is there another way of achieving this in vb?

I find it strange that the FileDialog class doesn't allow this because Word, Excel and Access all have this exact SaveAs feature built-in.

I realise that the FileDialog can created as a FilePicker (msoFileDialogFilePicker) which does allow filters, but then this doesn't allow a file to be selected that doesn't yet exist, which defeats the whole point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @AlexK mentioned the only way to do this is using a windows API call. See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa140112%28v=office.10%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

That appears to be a restriction of that particular class for some reason, so how about;

```
Dim vResult As Variant
vResult = Application.GetSaveAsFilename("default.blah", "blah files,*.blah,Text file,*.txt,All files,*.*", 0, "Title")
If VarType(vResult) = vbBoolean Then
    MsgBox "cancelled"
Else
    MsgBox vResult
End If
```

Comment: Application.GetSaveAsFilename is only available in Excel. I was hoping for a more general answer so I can use it with Access.

Comment: Only other way I can thing of is the GetSaveFileName API, there are lots of VBA examples (or invoking excels GetSaveAsFilename via COM in access but that seems a bit nasty)