# PowerPoint VBA Save As Dialog file filter

Tags: vba, powerpoint

How do I set 1 or more Save As Dialog file filter in PowerPoint VBA? Here is my code:

```
Private Sub save_file_Click()
Dim fd As FileDialog
Dim clicked As Boolean
Set fd = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogSaveAs)
With fd
    .InitialFileName = ActivePresentation.path & "\*.note"
    .AllowMultiSelect = False
    .ButtonName = "Save"
    .Title = "Save File"
    '-- Normal Filters are not allowed on FileDialogSaveAs --
    '.Filters.Clear
    '.Filters.Add "Note Files", "*.note"
    '.Filters.Add "Text Files", "*.txt"
    '.Filters.Add "All Files", "*.*"
End With
clicked = fd.Show
If clicked Then
    Open fd.SelectedItems(1) For Input As #1
    Print #1, text_box.Text
    Close intFileNum
End If
End Sub
```

Any Ideas?

In case it makes a difference: I'm not trying to make an ppt export to HTML, but save a file that's custom (`.note`) in a User Form (window).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Powerpoint VBA Macro Save As Dialog File Filter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22685594/powerpoint-vba-macro-save-as-dialog-file-filter)

Comment: The only thing close is setting the `.InitialFileName` property to something like `"*.txt"`. This forces the use of txt extension, though it will not show in the file dialog.

Comment: I've tried that, and it didn't work.

Comment: Well, it does work, but not exactly the way you'd expect it. And that way you can only have one extension. But you can force using that one extension. Anyway, if you read the linked discussion, you will find out that this seems impossible. You'd have to use another way.

Comment: Thanks, but I didn't see anything helpful.

Comment: Perhaps I'm misunderstanding something here, but it looks like you're letting the user choose a file to OPEN, not to SAVE.  If that's correct, shouldn't you be using msoFileDialogOpen instead?

Comment: No, the user SAVEs the text in a box to a file (like a text editor, but I'm not making a text editor).

Comment: OK, my mistake.  Thanks.

Comment: That's ok. Any ideas?? I'll try to look it up more but I don't think there is a way.